# Launching an Asynctask within onActivityResult()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onactivityresult

Is use an intent with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to choose a XML file. Within onActivityResult() I launch an asynctask to read this XML-file into a database.

I'd like the asynctask to show a progressbar to make sure it finishes before the app proceeds due to error handling and expected UI changes.

The chooser dialog that the intent creates is displayed as long as the asynctask is executed - ie the application is still in the onActivityResult() block,  and there are no progressdialog shown. The onPostExecute() is called AFTER onActivityResult() ends.

I've also tried to use .get() the make the asynctask finish before the app proceeds, but with no luck...

I think it boils down to wrong logic on my part...

Everything is happening in one activity except that importDB is a class of its own.

The intent is startet this way...

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/xml");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select XML"), RC_IMPORT_FILE);
```

...and the onActivityResult() looks like this...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RC_IMPORT_FILE:
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        importDB(new File(uri.toString()), uri, false);
                    };
                break;
        ... more switch statements...
    }
}
```

...and importDB looks like this...

```
private void importDB(File file, Uri uri, boolean xmlRaw, Context context) {
    int error = 0;

    ImportDataBase importDataBase = new ImportDataBase();
    importDataBase.setContext(this);
    importDataBase.setUri(uri);
    importDataBase.xmlRaw(xmlRaw);
    try {
        importDataBase.execute("ImportDB").get();
    }   catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        logException(TAG, "importDB", ee);
        error = 1;
    }   catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        logException(TAG, "importDB", ie);
        error = 2;
    }
}
```

...and the async task (ImportDataBase) looks like this...

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ImportDataBase extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

private static final String TAG = "ImportDataBase";

private Context context;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private Uri uri = null;
private InputStream xmlStream = null;

private XMLParser xmlParser;
private boolean xmlRaw = true;
private int errorCode = 0;

public void xmlRaw(boolean xmlRaw) {
    this.xmlRaw = xmlRaw;
}

public void setUri(Uri uri) { this.uri = uri; }
public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) { this.xmlStream = inputStream; }
public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = this.context;
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();
    xmlParser = new XMLParser();
    xmlParser.xmlRaw(xmlRaw);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
    String result = "0";
    int error = 0;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        if (uri != null) inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            else inputStream = this.xmlStream;
    }   catch (Exception e) {
        result = "1000";
    }

    if (error == 0) {
        try {
            xmlParser.readXML(inputStream);
        }   catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                result ="10";
        }   catch (Exception e) {
                result ="10";
        }

    }   else result = "31"; 

    switch (xmlParser.getError()) {
        case 1 : result = "10"; break; // XML Parser error
        case 2 : result = "15"; break; // URLERROR;
        case 3 : result = "30"; break; // IOFileError
        case 4 : result = "31"; break; // FileError;
        case 5 : result = "32"; break; // FileDoesNotExists;
        default : result = "0";
    }

    try {
        inputStream.close();
    }   catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    super.onPostExecute(string);
    String error = "";
    if (Integer.valueOf(string) > 0) {
        switch (Integer.valueOf(string)) {
            case 1:
                error = "You need to update the app to the newest version!";
                errorCode =1;
            break;
            case 10 :
                error = "XML parser error! Wrong file?";
                errorCode =10;
            break;
            case 15 :
                error = "Wrong URL!";
                errorCode =15;
            break;
            case 30 :
                error = "File read/Write error!";
                errorCode =30;
                break;
            case 31 :
                error = "File error";
                errorCode =31;
                break;
            case 32 :
                error = "File does not exsits!";
                errorCode =32;
                break;
            case 99 :
                error = "Unknwon XML parser error!";
                errorCode =99;
                break;
            case 100:
                error = "Database error! Retry or reinstall app!";
                errorCode =100;
            break;
            case 1000:
                error = "Unknown error!";
                errorCode =1000;
            break;
            default:
                error = "Unknwon error!";
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
    if ( progressDialog.isShowing() ) progressDialog.dismiss();
}

public int getError() {
    return this.errorCode;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can make the app wait for the asynctask to finish? Is it possible to close the dialog window inside onActivityResult() before I call importDB() and hopefully display a progressbar?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should **never** block anything. I would use an AsyncTask with displaying a ProgressDialog upon start and hiding it upon completion:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // blahblah
                    if (data != null) {
                        new ImportTask(new File(uri.toString()), uri).execute(); 
                    }
   // blahblah
}

class ImportTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private File file;
  private Uri uri;

  ImportTask( File file, Uri uri ){
    this.file = file;
    this.uri = uri;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground( Void... voids ) {
    importDB(file, uri, false);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute( Void res ) {
    progressDialog.hide();
  }      
}
```

This way you may decide to do other stuff in parallel during the `importDB()` is running.

Comment: Maybe I was a litle bit unclear. I've tried to display a progressbar, but since the file dialog window that the intent created is open until the asynctask reaches onPostExecute(), the progressbar is never shown during onPreExecute and doInBackground(). The funny thing is that progressbar.isShowing() returns true...

Comment: not sure what you mean. usually the activity open with `startActivityForResult()` is closed just before the `onActivityResult` is executed

Comment: I've tried this in an emulator API 23 and my phone a samsung s6 with android 6. I've put a Thread.sleep inside doInBackground() in the asynctask called in onActivityResult() and the dialog with the files to choose from is displayed during this sleep. It seems like the activity/intent is closed after onAcitivtyResult() finishes...

Comment: why didn't you show your AsyncTask in the OQ? It's weird, you are asking about something, but showing anything but the code you are asking about...

Comment: I've pasted the asynctask aswell.

Comment: `progressDialog = this.context;` this is REALLY strange

Comment: if you define a `progressDialog` and the `ImportDataBase` in your activity, then you should be able to access the former directly from the later. If not, then just add the activity's progressDialog as constructor arg of the async-task